# Has AlphaVantage stopped NSE stock quotes data?

Tags: equities, programming

I have been using AlphaVantage to get the historic data for NSE stocks (NSE= National Stock Exchange of India Ltd.). But since past 1 month the API has stopped returning data for NSE stocks. It returns data for NASDAQ stocks.

I tried searching the internet and the closest I found was [this question of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62589253/1047998) but it was also not answered. I am using below URL to fetch the data.’

[https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=NSE:HDFCBANK&apikey={API_KEY}](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=NSE:HDFCBANK&apikey=%7BAPI_KEY%7D)

I have emailed their support email but haven't heard back from them. Has AlphaVantage stopped NSE stock quotes data? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not the Alpha Vantage helpdesk.

Comment: Please contact Alpha Vantage directly.